# apache2 log to journald

Tags: apache, logging, systemd

Is there an opportunity to write the log messages of apache (V2.4) to the journalctl/journald logs instead to log to a file?

(I've seen Apache2.5 will have a [mod_journald](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_journald.html) to allow this task)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could set a custom log in your httpd.conf.

```
CustomLog "|/bin/logger -t access_log -p user.info" <log-formatters>
```

See the Apache docs for the formatting variables.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

Comment: On my system: the path to the logger was `/usr/bin/logger`